# Get Emacs to ignore *.orig files

Tags: version-control, emacs, ignore

I end up having a bunch of *.orig files sitting around, from hg reverts.  It's annoying when I find myself editing foo.c.orig instead of foo.c by mistake.  (I use ido-mode and the first match is not always the shortest.)

Is there a way to tell Emacs to ignore *.orig files as though they were *~ files?  I'm not having much luck with google -- I've found a million pages telling me how to change where it saves its own backup files, but not how to ignore others.

Comment: you can't find the answer easily, but because it's emacs you KNOW there must be a way...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`(add-to-list 'completion-ignored-extensions ".orig")`